# Get input min value from xml to xslt

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

How can I get a value from xml to xslt inside a html input tag as min, max and increment value? And I would like to validate this with javascript so that user can only enter value in between min and max value. below is what I like to achieve.

xml file

```
<options minimum="1" maximum="10" increment="1"/>
```

xslt file

```
<input type="number" name="amount" min="$minimum" max="$maximum"></input>
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Purely in terms of XSLT, you can use [Attribute Value Templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates) for this.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <xsl:template match="options">
    <input type="number" name="amount" min="{@minimum}" max="{@maximum}" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The curly braces indicate an expression to be evaluated, not output literally, and so the `min` attribute for the `input` element would be set to the value of the `minimum` attribute on the `options` element.

How you then use these `min` and `max` attributes in Javascript should really be addressed as a separate question.